# Get last added product in minicart magento2

Tags: magento2, checkout, addtocart

After **product** is **added to cart**, I want to open minicart and mark it with some styles. I found http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/141507/magento-2-open-minicart-when-item-is-added how to open it. But dont know how to get last added.

Comment: Did u try this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/123329/pop-up-minicart-when-i-add-a-product-to-the-cart-magento-2 (pinicio's answer)...This works on the last item added to cart, ie) recently added item will pop up. i tried its working

Comment: yes. I use this to show minicart. But question is about how to mark last added product in minicart?

Answer (score 0):

I havent tried it out, just to give you a picture. you can try this out in your block:

This is to get the last product item added to cart.

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
    array $data = []
 ) {
    $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
}  

$productID=$this->_checkoutSession->getLastAddedProductId(true);
echo $productID."<br>";
```

Comment: This doesn't work if I add again product that already is in cart, it will get wrong product by getLastAddedProductId.