# Auto Show Cart Sidebar when product added to cart

Tags: cart, addtocart, popup, sidebar

Is there any way I can make the cart sidebar pop up when a product is added to the cart. As per the below:

[image: cartsidebar]

As opposed to having to click on the cart button at the top of the page to bring it up.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Magento1 Or Magento2

Answer (score 0):

See Following Links have complete solutions :

1. [Pop up minicart when I add a product to the cart magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/123329/pop-up-minicart-when-i-add-a-product-to-the-cart-magento-2/140569#140569)
2. [Magento 2 Open minicart when item is added](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/141507/magento-2-open-minicart-when-item-is-added/141510#141510)