# How can i open mini cart on add of a product

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, cart, mini-cart

I am using the below link to create an observer.

[Magento 2 Open minicart when item is added](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/141507/magento-2-open-minicart-when-item-is-added/141510?newreg=e23298595b1d4d04844f224a3c20bc44)

My question is what code will come here

```
if ($cartUpdated) {
    // open mini cart
}
```

How can i open the mini cart?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento 2 Open minicart when item is added](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/141507/magento-2-open-minicart-when-item-is-added)

Comment: What code will be there //open mini cart

Comment: In this link, you have detail answer. https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-PWA-Theming-Layout/Show-minicart-in-header-when-adding-a-product-to-cart/m-p/50424/highlight/true#M740

Answer (score 0):

You need to create module for that

**create default.xml in : Company/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/default.xml**

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
  <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="minicart.autoopen" template="Company_ModuleName::minicart_open.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

Now **create Company/ModuleName/view/frontend/templates/minicart_open.phtml**

Inside minicart_open.phtml we need to call our js file (component) by attaching it to the parent div of the minicart. In this case, [data-block='minicart'].

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
     "[data-block='minicart']" : {
        "Company_ModuleName/js/view/minicart_open" : {}
     }
}
</script>
```

Create 
**Company/ModuleName/view/frontend/web/js/view/minicart_open.js**

```
define(["jquery/ui","jquery"], function(Component, $){
    return function(config, element){
        var minicart = $(element);
        minicart.on('contentLoading', function () {
            minicart.on('contentUpdated', function () {
                minicart.find('[data-role="dropdownDialog"]').dropdownDialog("open");
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Now mini cart will open automatically after product added.

Please reefer this link: https://github.com/navinbhudiya/magento2-minicart-open. I think you are reusing this and you can find the files not mentioned here in this link.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a mixin to the `Magento_Checkout/js/view/minicart` file with the add to cart listener there.

`Vendor/Theme/requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/view/minicart': {
                'Magento_Checkout/js/view/minicart-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`Vendor/Theme/Magento_Checkout/js/view/minicart-mixin.js`

```
define(['jquery', 'ko'], function ($) {
    'use strict';

    return function (Component) {
        return Component.extend({
            /**
             * @returns {*}
             */
            initialize: function () {
                this._super();

                this.element = $('[data-block="minicart"]');

                this.setupAddToCartListener();

                return this;
            },

            /**
             * Set up listeners for adding to cart and updating cart.
             * Open minicart once cart is fully updated.
             */
            setupAddToCartListener: function () {
                var self = this;

                this.element.on('contentLoading', function () {
                    self.element.on('contentUpdated', function () {
                        self.openMinicart();
                    });
                });
            },

            /**
             * Open minicart.
             */
            openMinicart: function () {
                this.element.find('[data-role="dropdownDialog"]').dropdownDialog('open');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Too late for the answer, but this could help others.
I solve this issue by the help of this blog:
https://webarchers.com/popup-minicart-when-product-add-to-the-cart-magento-2/
All you need is to add some custom JS to your phtml file like below:

```
$(document).on('click','.tocart',function(event){
        // console.log("incopyright")
        var minicart = $('[data-block="minicart"]');
        setTimeout(function() {
            minicart.find('[data-role="dropdownDialog"]').dropdownDialog('open');
        }, 3000);
        setTimeout(function() {
            minicart.find('[data-role="dropdownDialog"]').dropdownDialog('close');
        }, 10000);
         
        event.stopPropagation();
});
```